# Kafka Connect: No tasks created for a connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We are running Kafka Connect (Confluent Platform 5.4, ie. Kafka 2.4) in a distributed mode using Debezium (MongoDB) and Confluent S3 connectors.
When adding a new connector via the REST API the connector is created in RUNNING state, but no tasks are created for the connector.

Pausing and resuming the connector does not help.
When we stop all workers and then start them again, the tasks are created and everything runs as it should.

The issue is not caused by the connector plugins, because we see the same behaviour for both Debezium and S3 connectors. Also in debug logs I can see that Debezium is correctly returning a task configuration from the Connector.taskConfigs() method.

Can somebody tell me what to do se we can add connectors without restarting the workers?
Thanks.

**Configuration details**

The cluster has 3 nodes with the following *connect-distributed.properties*:

```
bootstrap.servers=kafka-broker-001:9092,kafka-broker-002:9092,kafka-broker-003:9092,kafka-broker-004:9092
group.id=tdp-QA-connect-cluster

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets-qa
offset.storage.replication.factor=3
offset.storage.partitions=5

config.storage.topic=connect-configs-qa
config.storage.replication.factor=3

status.storage.topic=connect-status-qa
status.storage.replication.factor=3
status.storage.partitions=3

offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

rest.host.name=tdp-QA-kafka-connect-001
rest.port=10083
rest.advertised.host.name=tdp-QA-kafka-connect-001
rest.advertised.port=10083

plugin.path=/opt/kafka-connect/plugins,/usr/share/java/

security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/kafka/ssl/kafka-connect.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=<secret>
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
producer.security.protocol=SSL
producer.ssl.truststore.location=/etc/kafka/ssl/kafka-connect.truststore.jks
producer.ssl.truststore.password=<secret>
consumer.security.protocol=SSL
consumer.ssl.truststore.location=/etc/kafka/ssl/kafka-connect.truststore.jks
consumer.ssl.truststore.password=<secret>

max.request.size=20000000
max.partition.fetch.bytes=20000000
```

**The connectors configuration**

Debezium example:

```
{
  "name": "qa-mongodb-comp-converter-task|1",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "mongodb.hosts": "mongodb-qa-001:27017,mongodb-qa-002:27017,mongodb-qa-003:27017",
    "mongodb.name": "qa-debezium-comp",
    "mongodb.ssl.enabled": true,
    "collection.whitelist": "converter[.]task",
    "tombstones.on.delete": true
  }
}
```

S3 example:

```
{
  "name": "qa-s3-sink-task|1",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
    "topics": "qa-debezium-comp.converter.task",
    "topics.dir": "data/env/qa",
    "s3.region": "eu-west-1",
    "s3.bucket.name": "<bucket-name>",
    "flush.size": "15000",
    "rotate.interval.ms": "3600000",
    "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
    "format.class": "custom.kafka.connect.s3.format.plaintext.PlaintextFormat",
    "schema.generator.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator",
    "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner",
    "schema.compatibility": "NONE",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": false,
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": false,
    "transforms": "ExtractDocument",
    "transforms.ExtractDocument.type":"custom.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractDocument$Value"
  }
}
```

The connectors are created using curl:
`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @<json_file> http:/<connect_host>:10083/connectors`

Comment: Faced the same issue many times (https://stackoverflow.com/q/55622904/7109598), but no solution was found

Comment: Never have had this problem. Please show all relevant configs, commands, installation details, etc.... cc @Iskuskov

Comment: @cricket_007 I added the configuration details. We add the connectors via the REST API using `curl -X POST ...`

Comment: Thats one file... Where is your Connector JSON? What command are you using to run the connector? What OS? What RAM & Heap settings?

Comment: btw, `max.request.size` needs to be prefixed with `producer` and `max.partition.fetch.bytes` with `consumer`

Comment: Are you able to individually describe each of the topics in the config? Do they all look healthy?

Comment: @cricket_007 I added the connector JSON examples. We have 3 differently sized clusters that all display the same problem, the Xmx vary from 1G to 6G. The topics look healthy and after the workers are restarted everything works fine until we try to add another connector.

Comment: All I can say is that tasks get distributed in the cluster. There is no guarantee all connectors always have running tasks. You may be able to see the rebalancing if you plot some JMX values, but restarting the cluster shouldnt be necessary.

Comment: I think I've faced this issue in the past. If I recall correctly, renaming the connectors' names did the trick for me. I know it doesn't make any sense at all but it might be worth trying it.

Comment: Yes, renaming connector is workaround solution. But it's not clear why this situation happened

Comment: @Iskuskov Do you have Confluent Support? Did you open any JIRAs? If you think it's a bug, there are more targeted audiences to reach out to

Comment: > Did you open any JIRAs: My bad, no. I tryed to ask on StackOverflow and Confluent Slack, but there is no result.
Over the past six months, everything is ok and now I doesn't have logs or some other helpful context.

Comment: @user2732824, would you like to open Jira ticket about this issue?

Comment: Creating a jira issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA/issues/ would probably help with investigation. Please include logs in the ticket (redacted if needed). Debug level will be quite more informative with respect to how tasks are created and are assigned during a rebalance. Also, might worth checking whether you experience the issue with CP 5.3.2 too or try each of the three options for `connect.protocol`. Also, make sure that Connect's internal topics are created with the right settings (config topic needs to be compacted).

Comment: I think it is insane that Kafka Connect doesn't log a WARN or ERROR with information on why the task can't be created or sustained.  I added a comment here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9747

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the `|` character in the names of the connectors. Generally special characters in connector names were not properly url-encoded during a communication between workers in older Kafka Connect versions. More details in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9747

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so i changed the name of the connector and create a new one, it worked but I don't know the source of this problem because we have no information in kafka-connect logs.

Comment: Changing the name worked for me too. Weird...

Answer (score 0):

Delete the connector and create it again with a different `database.server.id`. Repeat this process until task(s) show up.

It worked for me after 6-7 trials, not sure why. Pausing and resuming, restarting the connector/tasks did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

I got empty `tasks` when deploying a different connector at [Tasks are empty after deploying ElasticsearchSinkConnector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71518638/tasks-are-empty-after-deploying-elasticsearchsinkconnector/71518871#71518871)

Adding these two to the `config` when deploy the connector will help locate the issue about why the task failed.

```
        "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
        "errors.log.enable": "true"
```

In my case, instead of empty `tasks`, it will show why it failed:

**GET /connectors/elasticsearch-sink/status**

```
{
    "name": "elasticsearch-sink",
    "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "10.xxx.xxx.xxx:8083"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "state": "FAILED",
            "worker_id": "10.xxx.xxx.xxx:8083",
            "trace": "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group: connect-elasticsearch-sink\n"
        }
    ],
    "type": "sink"
}
```