# Tasks are empty after deploying ElasticsearchSinkConnector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I tried to deploy **ElasticsearchSinkConnector** by

**POST /connectors**

```
{
    "name": "elasticsearch-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
        "type.name": "_doc",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "my_db_server.public.my_table",
        "connection.url": "https://my-elasticsearch.com:9200",
        "connection.username": "xxx",
        "connection.password": "xxx",
        "key.ignore": "true",
        "schema.ignore": "true",
        "elastic.security.protocol": "SSL",
        "elastic.https.ssl.keystore.location": "path/to/keystore.jks",
        "elastic.https.ssl.keystore.password": "xxx",
        "elastic.https.ssl.key.password": "xxx",
        "elastic.https.ssl.keystore.type": "JKS",
        "elastic.https.ssl.truststore.location": "path/to/truststore.jks",
        "elastic.https.ssl.truststore.password": "xxx",
        "elastic.https.ssl.truststore.type": "JKS",
        "elastic.https.ssl.protocol": "TLS"
    }
}
```

It successfully deployed, however, when I check status by

**GET /connectors/elasticsearch-sink/status**

`tasks` is empty array `[]`:

```
{
    "name": "elasticsearch-sink",
    "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "10.xxx.xxx.xxx:8083"
    },
    "tasks": [],
    "type": "sink"
}
```

I found this [Kafka Connect: No tasks created for a connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60334554/kafka-connect-no-tasks-created-for-a-connector)

However, I tried those two answers inside, both changing name, and deleting ElasticsearchSinkConnector then redeploy multiple times didn't work for me.

Also, there is no logs in the Kafka Connect pod.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding these two to the ElasticsearchSinkConnector config

```
        "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
        "errors.log.enable": "true"
```

in the config so like

**POST /connectors**

```
{
    "name": "elasticsearch-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
        "type.name": "_doc",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "my_db_server.public.my_table",
        "connection.url": "https://my-elasticsearch.com:9200",
        "connection.username": "xxx",
        "connection.password": "xxx",
        "key.ignore": "true",
        "schema.ignore": "true",
        "elastic.security.protocol": "SSL",
        "elastic.https.ssl.keystore.location": "path/to/keystore.jks",
        "elastic.https.ssl.keystore.password": "xxx",
        "elastic.https.ssl.key.password": "xxx",
        "elastic.https.ssl.keystore.type": "JKS",
        "elastic.https.ssl.truststore.location": "path/to/truststore.jks",
        "elastic.https.ssl.truststore.password": "xxx",
        "elastic.https.ssl.truststore.type": "JKS",
        "elastic.https.ssl.protocol": "TLS",
        "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
        "errors.log.enable": "true"
    }
}
```

And this time when I check status by

**GET /connectors/elasticsearch-sink/status**

`tasks` shows error now:

```
{
    "name": "elasticsearch-sink",
    "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "10.xxx.xxx.xxx:8083"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "state": "FAILED",
            "worker_id": "10.xxx.xxx.xxx:8083",
            "trace": "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group: connect-elasticsearch-sink\n"
        }
    ],
    "type": "sink"
}
```

Now just need fix the permission issue.

Also, I found a good article about how to debug: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues/