# Kafka Connect with a JdbcConnectionSource connector fails to create task (connector is RUNNING but task is not)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

It seems like rather often I create a Kafka Connect connector from the JdbcConnectionSource based on a query, and the connector is created successsfully with status "RUNNING", but no task is created.  Looking in the console logs of my container, I see no indication that anything is wrong that I can tell: no errors, no warnings, no explanation of why the task failed.  I can get other connectors to work, but sometimes one doesn't.

**How can one get more information to troubleshoot when a connector fails to create a RUNNING task?**

I'll post an example of my connector config below.

I am using Kafka Connect 5.4.1-ccs.

Connector config (it is an Oracle Database behind JDBC):

```
{
    "name": "FiscalYear",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": 1,
        "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost.example.com)(PORT=1521))(LOAD_BALANCE=OFF)(FAILOVER=OFF)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MY_DB_PRI)(UR=A)))",
        "connection.user":"myuser",
        "connection.password":"mypass",
        "mode": "timestamp",
        "timestamp.column.name": "MAINT_TS",
        "topic.prefix": "MyTeam.MyTopicName",
        "poll.interval.ms": 5000,
        "value.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "numeric.mapping": "best_fit",

        "_comment": "The query is wrapped in `select * from ()` so that JdbcSourceConnector can automatically append a WHERE clause.",
        "query": "SELECT * FROM (SELECT fy_nbr, min(fy_strt_dt) fy_strt_dt, max(fy_end_dt) fy_end_dt FROM myuser.fsc_dt fd WHERE fd.fy_nbr >= 2020 and fd.fy_nbr < 2022 group by fy_nbr)/* outer query must have no WHERE clause so that the source connector can append one of its own */"
    }
}
```

And the Dockerfile that creates my worker:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest

# each "CONNECT_" env var refers to a Kafka Connect setting; e.g. CONNECT_REST_PORT refers to setting rest.port
#  see also https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/allconfigs.html

ENV CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="d.mybroker.example.com:9092"
ENV CONNECT_REST_PORT="8083"
ENV CONNECT_GROUP_ID="MyGroup2" 

ENV CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC="MyTeam.ConnectorConfig" 
ENV CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC="MyTeam.ConnectorOffsets" 
ENV CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC="MyTeam.ConnectorStatus" 

ENV CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" 
ENV CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" 

ENV CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"  
ENV CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" 

ENV CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL="INFO"

COPY ojdbcDrivers /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc
```

(I also set the REST advertised hostname environment variable via my Helm chart, so that's why it isn't set in the above.)

After it spins up, I create the connector, then get this from the REST "/status":

```
{"name":"FiscalYear","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"10.1.2.3:8083"},"tasks":[],"type":"source"}
```

Comment: Your issue is quite common. See for example this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60334554/kafka-connect-no-tasks-created-for-a-connector#comment106736969_60334554)

Comment: Also please check your config topic. Is it compact?

Comment: Please see this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9747

Comment: I added a comment to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9747 .  Sad that there seems to be no good answer.

Comment: My topic is not compacted.

Comment: Did you try to use compacted topics?

Comment: No, why should I need to?

Comment: Please check this [doc](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#distributed-mode):  > It is important that these internal topics have a high replication factor, a compaction cleanup policy, and an appropriate number of partitions.

Answer (score 2):

> How can one get more information to troubleshoot when a connector fails to create a RUNNING task?

I would increase the logging level on your Kafka Connect worker. 
Since you're using Apache Kafka 2.4 you can do this dynamically, which is rather useful. Issue this REST API call to your Kafka Connect worker:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/admin/loggers/io.confluent \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"level": "TRACE"}'
```

This bumps up all messages for any Confluent connector to `TRACE`. It also returns a list of the individually loggers, from which you can cherry-pick different loggers and turn their specific loglevel up or down as required. For example:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/admin/loggers/io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.DatabaseDialects \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"level": "INFO"}'
```

Ref: https://rmoff.net/2020/01/16/changing-the-logging-level-for-kafka-connect-dynamically/

Comment: Great, I tried this and got COPIOUS messages out.  I then switched level to DEBUG hoping to get fewer messages, but sadly it gave me nothing.  From the second half of your answer, I need to set some of the nuanced loggers to DEBUG and set others to TRACE--any suggestions which ones?

Comment: To learn, I deliberately changed my sql so that I failed to SELECT the column that is specified in `timestamp.column.name`.  I then created the connector, and sure enough no task was created.  I see a ton of DEBUG and TRACE logs, but all I can pull out that looks relevant is `Finished creating connector MyConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)` and `Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)`.  No clues as to whether the SQL is bad or that the timestamp column doesn't exist.  Any further tips on how to get better logs?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Also related is this, if you have time to help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62217473/7453