# Kafka Connector's task list is empty

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

After kafka startup sometimes I get this behaviour (not all the time - seems random).

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectRestException: Internal request missing required signature\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:133)
```

This ~5 message of these get print to the console every seconds.

curl-ing **`host:8083/connectors/myconnector`**  shows that the connector is running (max task config set to 10) howevery the task list is empty (it is **NOT** UNASSIGNED ,but it is empty)

At next startup it works fine

Comment: Looks like this ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9747 is related to youe issue. (similar SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622904/kafka-jdbc-sink-connector-no-tasks-assigned))